# SetValidator for complex properties not working

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have the following validation class for "Expense" entity:

```
public class ExpenseBaseValidator : AbstractValidator<Expense>
{
    public ExpenseBaseValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Description).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Amount).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.BusinessID).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("BusinessID is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.ExpenseTypeID).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("ExpenseTypeID is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.CreatedDate).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Transaction).SetValidator(new TransactionValidator());
    }
}
```

Then I have validation class for Transaction which is a complex property in Expense class above:

```
public class TransactionBaseValidator : AbstractValidator<Transaction>
{
    public TransactionBaseValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.BankAccountID).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("BankAccountID is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.EmployeeID).NotEqual(0).WithMessage("EmployeeID is required.");
        RuleFor(x => x.TransactionDate).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.IsWithdrawal).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Amount).NotNull();
        RuleFor(x => x.Description).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.PaymentMethod).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.PaymentMethod).Length(0, 50).WithMessage("PaymentMethod can not exceed 50 characters");
    }
}
```

Now these are base classes and I call the validator using the following child classes respectively:

```
public class ExpenseValidator : ExpenseBaseValidator
{
    public ExpenseValidator()
        : base()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Transaction)
            .NotNull()
            .When(x => x.IsPaid == true)
            .WithMessage("An account transaction is required when the amount is paid.");

        RuleFor(x => x.DatePaid)
            .NotNull()
            .When(x => x.IsPaid == true)
            .WithMessage("Please enter the date when the expense was paid.");
    }
}
```

And Transaction child class:

```
public class TransactionValidator : TransactionBaseValidator
{
    public TransactionValidator() : base()
    {

    }
}
```

And these can have extra rules for validation and the base rules are called using the `base()` constructor.

And I validate the Expense object using this:

```
var validator = new ExpenseValidator();
var results = validator.Validate(oExpense);
```

Now this doesn't return the validation for the complex property transaction which I am using in the following way:

```
oExpense.Transaction = new Transaction();
oExpense.Transaction.Amount = oExpense.Amount;
oExpense.Transaction.BankAccountID = ddlAccounts.SelectedItem.Value.ToInt();
oExpense.Transaction.TransactionDate = oExpense.DatePaid.Value;
oExpense.Transaction.IsWithdrawal = true;
oExpense.Transaction.Description = oExpense.Description;
oExpense.Transaction.IsDeleted = false;
// I dont set the below and it should give me validation error:
// oExpense.Transaction.EmployeeID = 10;
```

I don't set the EmployeeID and it should give me validation error when I call validator for expense object as it has `SetValidator()` for the Transaction property and the Transaction is also not null as I already set `new Transaction()`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I used the validation you posted and created the related classes/properties based on what was included in the validators. Building up the `Transaction` object from the posted sample, I received the following validation errors:

- 'Description' should not be empty.
- 'Amount' must not be empty.
- BusinessID is required.
- ExpenseTypeID is required.
- **EmployeeID is required.**
- 'Amount' must not be empty.
- 'Description' should not be empty.
- 'Payment Method' should not be empty.

Put a breakpoint on `var results = validator.Validate(oExpense);` and verify the value of `oExpense.Transaction.EmployeeID`. *If the value is not 0, then `EmployeeID` is being set somewhere else.*

For reference, here is the basic console app I created:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Results;

namespace so.FluentValidationComplexProperties
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var oExpense = new Expense();
            oExpense.Transaction = new Transaction();
            oExpense.Transaction.Amount = oExpense.Amount;
            oExpense.Transaction.BankAccountID = 10;
            oExpense.Transaction.TransactionDate = DateTime.Today;
            oExpense.Transaction.IsWithdrawal = true;
            oExpense.Transaction.Description = oExpense.Description;
            oExpense.Transaction.IsDeleted = false;
            // I dont set the below and it should give me validation error:
            // oExpense.Transaction.EmployeeID = 10;


            var validator = new ExpenseValidator();
            ValidationResult results = validator.Validate( oExpense );

            results.Errors.ToList().ForEach( Console.WriteLine );

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.Write( "--done--" );
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }


    public class ExpenseBaseValidator : AbstractValidator<Expense>
    {
        public ExpenseBaseValidator()
        {
            RuleFor( x => x.Description ).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor( x => x.Amount ).NotNull();
            RuleFor( x => x.BusinessID ).NotEqual( 0 ).WithMessage( "BusinessID is required." );
            RuleFor( x => x.ExpenseTypeID ).NotEqual( 0 ).WithMessage( "ExpenseTypeID is required." );
            RuleFor( x => x.CreatedDate ).NotNull();
            RuleFor( x => x.Transaction ).SetValidator( new TransactionValidator() );
        }
    }

    public class TransactionBaseValidator : AbstractValidator<Transaction>
    {
        public TransactionBaseValidator()
        {
            RuleFor( x => x.BankAccountID ).NotEqual( 0 ).WithMessage( "BankAccountID is required." );
            RuleFor( x => x.EmployeeID ).NotEqual( 0 ).WithMessage( "EmployeeID is required." );
            RuleFor( x => x.TransactionDate ).NotNull();
            RuleFor( x => x.IsWithdrawal ).NotNull();
            RuleFor( x => x.Amount ).NotNull();
            RuleFor( x => x.Description ).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor( x => x.PaymentMethod ).NotEmpty();
            RuleFor( x => x.PaymentMethod ).Length( 0, 50 ).WithMessage( "PaymentMethod can not exceed 50 characters" );
        }
    }

    public class ExpenseValidator : ExpenseBaseValidator
    {
        public ExpenseValidator()
                : base()
        {
            RuleFor( x => x.Transaction )
                    .NotNull()
                    .When( x => x.IsPaid )
                    .WithMessage( "An account transaction is required when the amount is paid." );

            RuleFor( x => x.DatePaid )
                    .NotNull()
                    .When( x => x.IsPaid )
                    .WithMessage( "Please enter the date when the expense was paid." );
        }
    }

    public class TransactionValidator : TransactionBaseValidator
    {
        public TransactionValidator()
                : base() {}
    }


    public class Expense
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public int BusinessID { get; set; }
        public int ExpenseTypeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
        public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
        public DateTime DatePaid { get; set; }
    }

    public class Transaction
    {
        public int BankAccountID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
        public bool? IsWithdrawal { get; set; }
        public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```